# How can i change angular ngModel value from javascript/console?

Tags: javascript, angular

<input id="myId" [(ngModel)]="valueModel" />

Answer (score 0):

Select element - document.querySelector('#myId').select()
change value - document.execCommand('insertText', false, '8')

this will trigger angular and update the model value